# How to disable postback of radiobutton based on some conditions in asp.net on client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button, postback, selectedindexchanged

I have a radiobutton list defined in my form. When the user selects any option, we do a postback and then business logic is executed.
Now the problem is, I want to add a confirmation from user whenever he checks a radio button option; when the user selects OK then only I want to go ahead.

Sample Flow: 
    1. Assume FirstItem in radiobutton is checked.
    2. The user will go and select the second item - Then I want to add a confirmation like "Are you sure " - 
    3. If the user selects NO 
            Then I should revert the check changed without the postback
        Else 
          Perform the postback and then business logic

The code is as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCheckBoxes" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="LabourScheduleType_CheckedChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" onClick="confirmcheck();"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" onClick="confirmcheck();"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

The code-behind code is like this

I wrote a javascript function also to control the postback

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function confirmcheck() {
        var retVal = confirm("test");
        return retVal;
    }

</script>
```

I tried everything like adding an attribute like onclick and then returning false in the method and so on. Somehow the postback always happens and I do not know how to revert the check changed also ! I am going crazy over this from past 4 hours.

**EDIT1:**

I was searching over internet and found solution to half of my problem !

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCheckBoxes" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" OnCheckedChanged="aaa_cc"  GroupName="aa" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="test1" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" OnCheckedChanged="aaa_cc"  GroupName="aa" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="test2" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code behind file :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            RadioButton1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "this.blur(); return RadioClick(this);");
            RadioButton2.Attributes.Add("onClick", "this.blur(); return RadioClick(this);");
        }
    }
```

Javacript goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function RadioClick(radioButton)
    {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?'))
        {
            __doPostBack(radioButton.id,'');
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

**The only problem is when i return false, the value in radio button is lost i.e. none of the radio buttons are selected :(**

Answer (score 0):

Try `OnClientClick='return confirmcheck();'`. That value will be rendered as the value of the `onclick` attribute when the page is rendered. Also, returning the result will signal if the default processing will continue.

`OnClick` specifies the server-side event handler.

Comment: OnClientClick to which control - RadiobuttonList or ListItem ? I tried both it doesn't work ! The javascript function is not getting called and postback happens :(

Comment: [Here's an article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/aspnetcontrols/confirm-before-deleting-gridview-item) that shows how I did this. It wasn't with radio buttons but the principal is the same. I don't have Visual Studio handy right now but you should be able to figure out why it isn't working for you. What was the markup that got rendered? Did it render onclick?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2724182/443568  - this says that there is no OnClientClick event !

Comment: Did you mean to say that there is no `OnClientClick` attribute for either the RadioButtonList or ListItem controls? (Because I know for a fact that most controls support this attribute.) But if it's not supported then `OnClick` should pass through unchanged. Try modifying your code to include the `return` like I have in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" onClick="if(!confirmcheck()) return false;"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" onClick="if(!confirmcheck()) return false;"></asp:ListItem>
```

return true or false in onClick will also prevent the postback to happen, so we only return when confirmcheck() is false.

I tested and it works

Comment: No it does not work ! It doesn't do post back at all ! And if I return false, it removes the checked state !

Answer (score 0):

Include "EnableViewState=true" in your HTML declaration of the radio buttons. Your EDIT1 solution should work after including this attribute, so if you return false, the state won't loose.